# How do I get only the part of an HTML tree which is above a certain tag with certain string BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML tree and only want a certain part of it. I.e. I only want the part of an HTML tree which is above a certain tag with string. The example contains only one `b` tag with `Notes` as string but there could be several.

```html
<br/>
Hello
<br/>
<b>
 Notes
</b>
<br/>
Hello
<a name="test">
  Hello2
</a>
```

should become

```html
<br/>
Hello
<br/>
```

With my code I only get the desired output as list but not as HTML tree.

```py
#book.html contains the example from above
openHtml = open('book.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(openHtml, 'html.parser')
all=soup.find_all('b')
for i in all:
    if i.text.strip() == 'Notes':
        pos = all.index(i)
soup = soup.find_all("b")[pos].find_all_previous(string=True)
print(soup)
```

How can I get the same result as HTML and not as list?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

I iterated over the list and removed every element after the desired tag and removed the tag itself from the end.

```py
openHtml = open('book.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(openHtml, 'html.parser')
all=soup.find_all('b')
for i in all:
    if i.text.strip() == 'Notes':
        pos = all.index(i)
for i in soup.find_all("b")[pos]:
    for j in i.find_all_next():
        j.extract()
soup.find_all('b')[-1].extract()
print(soup.prettify())
```